# Запись в файл,но есть ошибка!

Tags: c++

Всем Привет У меня проблемка Я создал консольное приложение и его код

```
// write_file.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> // работа с файлами
#include <iomanip> // манипуляторы ввода/вывода
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    // связываем объект с файлом, при этом файл открываем в режиме записи, предварительно удаляя все данные из него
    ofstream fout("License.txt", ios_base::out | ios_base::trunc);

    if (!fout.is_open()) // если файл небыл открыт 
    { 
     cout << "Файл не может быть Записан\n"; // напечатать соответствующее сообщение
     return 1; // выполнить выход из программы
    }

       fout << "data type" << endl;

        fout.close(); // программа больше не использует файл, поэтому его нужно закрыть
    cout << "БЕБЕБЕБЕ\n";
    system("pause >> void");
    return 0;
}
```

При запуске создается 2 файла а не один 1 файл License.txt а второй void без формата 
Но должен создаватся только  License.txt!

Answer (score 3):

А зачем писать так? -

```
system("pause >> void");
```

Просто вызываете команду

```
system("pause");
```

Comment: Но хотелься с system("pause >> void"); поставлю system("pause");
Спасибо!

Comment: А лучше такого вообще не делать. Вызывать новую команду -- бррр.

Answer (score 3):

Вы ведь сами в конце делаете вызов команды pause и перенаправляете ее вывод в файл с именем void. Можно перенаправлять вывод в /dev/null, чтобы такого не было.

Comment: Я так понимаю, человек пишет в винде.

Comment: Пусть cygwin поставит, там /dev/null есть.

Comment: какая прелесть

Comment: В винде аналогом /dev/null является просто nul

Comment: NUL: -- это еще с доса (а может и раньше)

Answer (score 2):

Видимо вот эта строчка system("pause >> void"); и создает второй